# Cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm currently working with Node JS to make a discord chatbot in which I am attempting to make connect four. At the moment the only thing I'm trying to do is draw the initial game board.

I'm getting an error:

> 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message' error.

This is my code which should draw a rectangular box (the game board).

```
const boardSquareDef = "| |"
const boardSquareRed = "|R|"
const boardSquareBlue = "|B|"

var defaultDrawnBoard;
var drawnBoardX;

var boardX = 7;
var boardY = 6;

var botChannel = client.channels.get("469825469697622029");

// This function is called elsewhere
function BoardDraw ()
{
  for (var i = 0; i >= boardX; i++) {
    drawnBoardX += boardSquareDef;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i >= boardY; i++) {
    defaultDrawnBoard += drawnBoardX + "\n";
  }

  botChannel.send(defaultDrawnBoard); // <--- error here!
}
```

I can't figure out why in the world the string isn't getting any text. Does anyone notice anything off?

Comment: This won't append anything to the `defaultDrawnBoard` is `boardX` or `boardY` have been modified to zero before this is called. Have you tried logging `boardX + " " + boardY + " " defaultDrawnBoard` just before `send`?

Comment: You should use `<=` in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to initialize **defaultDrawnBoard** & **drawnBoardX**, otherwise loop prints something like this `undefined|| || || |`

> var defaultDrawnBoard="";
>
> var drawnBoardX="";

Inside the BoardDraw function, use `i<=` instead of i>= as this is not letting the loop to start.

So your code should look like this,

```
const boardSquareDef = "| |"
const boardSquareRed = "|R|"
const boardSquareBlue = "|B|"

var defaultDrawnBoard="";
var drawnBoardX="";

var boardX = 7;
var boardY = 6;

var botChannel = client.channels.get("469825469697622029");

// This function is called elsewhere
function BoardDraw ()
{
  for (var i = 0; i <= boardX; i++) {
    drawnBoardX += boardSquareDef;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= boardY; i++) {
    defaultDrawnBoard += drawnBoardX + "\n";
  }

  botChannel.send(defaultDrawnBoard); // <--- error here!
}
```